# Inline VisualForce page not display in Edit

Tags: visualforce, page-layout

I just create visualforce page that contains only text and put it inside the page Layout as INLINE VISUALFORCE.I noticed this not display in Edit page but it only display in Detail page.Mean when I click New button, the inline VF is not display.But after I inserted one object then click on it,it will display.
How to make it display in Edit Layout.
[image]
[[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes In Edit layout you can't show the inline vf page.

If you want to show in edit page.

You need to override edit page. You need to build custom edit page that will create page

```
<apex:page standardController="MyCustomObject__c">
 <apex:form>
    <apex:inputField value="{!MyCustomObject__c.name}"/> <p/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

You need to ovverride you edit button on your custom object ex. MyCustomObject__c

Go to your custom object --> goto button,link section

[image]

Click on edit button. select **Override With** visualforce

[image]

select your above created VF page.

and save.

Hope this will help you

If you want this feature please vote here..

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Br8CAAS

Comment: I knew this already, but it frustrated because i have to create the whole new form just want to information text.thanks.

Comment: For now this is the only solution. If you need this feature pls vote in https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Br8CAAS this idea.